# Correct way to handle Requests in Laravel

Tags: laravel, request

I'm thinking about the right way to handle my requests.
At the moment I call a function and put the request input directly into the db query. Like this...

```
$groupid = Group::where('name', $request->input('groupname'))->select('id')->first();
```

Is it correct to do it like this? Or is it maybe better to define a variable (Is $groupname actually I variable?) before. Like this...

```
$groupname = $request->input('groupname');    
$groupid = Group::where('name', $groupname)->select('id')->first();
```

Or does it not matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter.

Comment: While writing code readability must be kept in mint so, second option is more efficient and readable. It will help you to use same variable multiple times (if required) easily.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, your first option is correct. 
in second option you are declaring a new variable and increasing your memory stack, which is not needed.

So you should get the value form the variable which is already created.

Moreover instead of getting input value from input function you can directly access $request property as `$groupid = Group::where('name', $request->groupname)->select('id')->first();`
This is my opion, there may be another option to do.